# Pass or Fail condition checking JTable

Tags: java, swing

I have design the JTable for Student Marklits. I have completed Total ,Average column.It is automatically changed when mark columns are  entered.But the Result column i can't know how to do.Pleaase suggest me the code.I have added my code here.

```
public Object getValueAt(int row,int column){

     if (column == 5) {
         Integer m1 = (Integer) getValueAt(row, 0);
         Integer m2 = (Integer) getValueAt(row, 1);
         Integer m3 = (Integer) getValueAt(row, 2);
         Integer m4 = (Integer) getValueAt(row, 3);
         Integer m5 = (Integer) getValueAt(row, 4);


         if (m1 != null && m2 != null && m3 != null && m4 != null && m5 != null ) {
             return m1+m2+m3+m4+m5;
         } else {
             return 0;
         }  
     }

     if (column == 6) {
         Integer tot = (Integer) getValueAt(row, 5);

         if (tot != null ) {
             return tot/5;
         } else {
             return 0.0;
         }  

     }

     if (column == 7) {
         Integer mm1 = (Integer) getValueAt(row, 0);
         Integer mm2 = (Integer) getValueAt(row, 1);
         Integer mm3 = (Integer) getValueAt(row, 2);
         Integer mm4 = (Integer) getValueAt(row, 3);
         Integer mm5 = (Integer) getValueAt(row, 4);

         if (mm1 >=35 && mm2 >=35 && mm3 >=35 && mm4 >=35 && mm5 >=35 ) {
             return "Pass";
         } else {
             return "Fail";
         }  
     }

     return super.getValueAt(row, column);

}
```

Comment: What is the wrong with your code? It is fine I guess. You have checked each and every mark > 35 and pass him. It is fine if that is the passing logic. Can't you see the output

Comment: didn't check your code, just: do the calculation in setValueAt/when filling the marks - then you wouldn't have to re-calc it whenever a value is needed